# Significato di "non fa che piazza e casa"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> *Mia madre.* Ma se c'è don Ciccio che è stato in America e, dopo aver versato ogni cosa alla posta, coi frutti **non fa che piazza e casa** e sta vestito sempre come un cavallaccio?

La mia domanda è sul significato della locuzione "non fa che piazza e casa" che appare in questo brano. Si tratta di un modo di dire? Ho cercato alla voce "piazza" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato questa espressione.

A proposito, il significato di "cavallaccio" viene spiegato precedentemente nel libro:

> Di fronte al caffè c'è il Casino dei Nobili o Cavallacci come noi qui, a Mineo, li chiamiamo. È un vecchio edificio in cui non sono mai entrato, con le porte chiuse in alto da vetri gialli e rossi e una terrazza all'entrata,  protetta da un'inferriata che si consuma e si fa rossastra di ruggine. I cavallacci una volta erano baroni o ricchi feudatari, ma oggi sono gli impiegati del Municipio, qualche prete e dei contadinotti che posseggono un paio di salme di terra e hanno i figli, a Catania, agli studi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi pare di capire che il personaggio in questione vive di rendita con gli interessi di quello che ha versato in posta; l'espressione *"non fa che piazza e casa"* significa secondo me appunto che non lavora, e divide il suo tempo tra stare a casa (a non far nulla) e bighellonare in piazza (ai bar, al caffè, ecc.).